# Impact of religious holidays whose dates shift in the Gregorian calendar

Tags: moving-window

I need to model and predict a quantitative variable that is heavily impacted by events, parties and celebrations. For I seek first to know the impact that has the religious festivals, the ramadan and the tabaski on my variable but the problem the date of these festivals are variable in the Gregorian calendar, therefore I do not know how to capture this effect.

Comment: Hi! What is the statistical unit in your study?

Comment: @utobiI work on monthly data of the amounts of outgoing payments at the counters of a bank

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing time series forecasting in the presence of such time-shifting predictors, then [De Livera et al. (2011)](https://doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.tm09771) would probably be of interest. Their proposed methodology (BATS/TBATS) aims at modeling and forecasting complex seasonality, and one of their applications actually is to Turkish electricity demand, which is heavily influenced by Eid al-Fitr and Eid al-Adha. An ungated version of the paper is [available at Rob Hyndman's site](https://robjhyndman.com/papers/ComplexSeasonality.pdf), and their method is implemented in the `forecast` package for R.

Comment: For readers unaware, Eid al-Fitr and Eid al-Adha are major holidays in Islam, which is the dominant religion in Turkey. They do not occur on the same day every (Gregorian) year.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan Kolassa
I will consult the article.
However, I would like to know if this method allows me to capture the punctual and average effects of Eid al-Fitr and Eid al-Adha on my variable of interest. That is to say, if at the end I can say that Eid al-Fitr and Eid al-Adha had an effect of such magnitude or such quantity (%) on my variable

Comment: You can post-process the estimated model and extract this kind of information.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Please Guidance on how to post-train and extract these effects...?

Comment: Please start working with the tools for a while first. If you get stuck, feel free to open a new question here, with a Minimal (!) Working (!) Example. You can link to that new question here, and I will try to find the time to help.